# Treegridview don't display in jqgrid jquery after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I am using Jqgrid Tree View model, i insert a node for tree view and reload but jqgrid display wrong. Please help me

This is before reload:

[image]

This is after reload:

[image]

[This is my Source](http://www.mediafire.com/download/fiwymt791wd76xp/demo.rar)

Please download it and help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

before refreshing jstree first destroy it and again rebuild it by using:

```
$("#tree-container").jstree("destroy");

// again call the method to create jstree
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry,I use jqtreegrid of jqgrid jquery

Comment: Then check there is some function to destroy the tree grid.